# jQuery submit ajax post on anchor click

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-post

When an anchor is clicked I send a POST request to a server cross browser to track a click. However the next page loads before the request receives a response and the request is aborted.

```
$('body').on('click', '.link a', function() {
    $.post('https://someserver.com/', {
        param: 'here'
    });
});
```

How can ensure the request receives a response before the page loads?

Comment: Yes you should do a `return false;` and before that you can do the post, and then inside the `complete: function(){}` callback a javascript redirect `window.location.href` :)

Comment: Or just copy JCOC611 answer, lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prevent the default action until you hear a response:

```
$('body').on('click', '.link a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    $.post('https://someserver.com/', {
        param: 'here',
        success: function(){
            window.location.href = href;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: small typo around the success callback function though `{ param: 'here' } .success(function() {})`

Comment: @AsaCarter seems to be working for me...looks like that is another valid syntax

Comment: Apologies, I was looking at the syntax for $.post in the the jQuery docs.